# jasmine-node cannot find spec module

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, jasmine, node-modules, jasmine-node

I have a barebones spec written in coffeescript:

```
# test/foobar.spec.coffee

describe "falsy test", ->
  it "should fail", ->
    expect(true).toBe false
```

when I run `jasmine-node --coffee test/foobar.spec.coffee` from the project directory, I get the following error:

```
Exception loading: /Users/myuser/programming/project/test/foobar.spec.coffee
{ [Error: Cannot find module '/Users/myuser/programming/project/test/foobar.spec'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

I am using:

```
node --version
v0.10.8

jasmine-node --version
1.13.0
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: I have the same problem. jasmine-node says `Exception loading: /home/user/code/node-spec/transition_spec.coffee
{ [Error: Cannot find module '/home/user/code/node-spec/transition_spec'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }`

Comment: @Dmitry Kolobov It looks like this may have been resolved in the latest version. Try running 'npm update -g' from the command line to retrieve the latest version and then rerun your specs.

Comment: @Dmitry Kolobov I'm currently using version 1.13.1. Check the output of 'jasmine-node --version'.

Comment: @A-Dubb, it seems you are correct. With jasmine-node 1.14.3 everything works as expected. Thank you!

Comment: @Dmitry Kolobov no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with other packages (require, supertest). It seems that if you install them globally (npm install -g) than you get this error. With a local installation (without -g option) everything seems to be normal.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered this error in a weird way.

The following code works,

```
function someFunc(){
     //do something
}

describe(testCases.testCaseRegister.name, async function(){
    someFunc();

    //ensure ample time for database to be setup properly
    await new Promise(done => setTimeout(done, 5000));
}
```

But when i changed to this, the error will appear and occasionally, a "Syntax Error: await is only valid in async function"

```
function someFunc(){
     //do something
     await new Promise(done => setTimeout(done, 5000));
}

describe(testCases.testCaseRegister.name, async function(){
    someFunc();

}
```

Switching back to my original code, resolved all these errors.

Comment: this does not relate to the question.